# Control number of Events processed parallely by azure function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I am trying to limit the number of events that are picked up and processed by my eventhub triggered azure function.

I have the value of eventHub:maxBatchSize in host.json to 8. But I can see that more than 8 events are being processed at a time. What should be the value of eventHub:prefetchCount ? Would it make a difference to change prefetchCount to achieve my goal (it is currently default) ?

Note: My azure function runs in an appservice plan.

Comment: It might be possible that you have multiple functions each picking up 8 messages. See if making the function a singleton helps (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#singleton)

Comment: I do not think that would solve my issue. I want to limit the function to specific number of parallel events processed at a time.

Comment: Are you using the array in method signature to enforce batch mode something like below public static async Task Run(string[] myEventHubMessage, TraceWriter log) .